# in Pandas how to replace a zero value with the nearest non nan value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the col look like :

```
NaN
859.0
NaN
NaN
0.0
NaN
```

and I would like to change the zero by the previous non NaN value, and don't change the other NaN,id get this :

```
NaN
859.0
NaN
NaN
859.0
NaN
```

I've tried replace with ffill, but can't manage to get the right output.

Any help welcome  !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ffill().shift()` will propagate the last non-null value forward, and then you can just assign any rows with value = 0 to that:

```
In [42]: s.ffill().shift()
Out[42]:
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    859.0
3    859.0
4    859.0
5      0.0
dtype: float64

In [43]: s[s==0] = s.ffill().shift()

In [44]: s
Out[44]:
0      NaN
1    859.0
2      NaN
3      NaN
4    859.0
5      NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

First replace `0` to missing values, use `ffill` for forward filling missing values and last replace missing values back by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['col'] = df['col'].mask(df['col'].eq(0)).ffill().mask(df['col'].isna())
print (df)
     col
0    NaN
1  859.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4  859.0
5    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this with last_valid_index:

say your column is in `df['col']`

```
for i,_ in df.iterrows():
    if df.loc[i,'col'] == 0:
        df.at[i,'col'] = df.loc[df.loc[:i-1,'col'].last_valid_index(),'col']
```

output:

```
     col
0    NaN
1  859.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4  859.0
5    NaN
```